# Replace if in array

Tags: php

I need to be able to swap given values if they are present in a multidimensional array.

```
$cars = array
(
  array("Volvo", "Silver", "Silver Metallic"),
  array("BMW", "Red", "Sunset Red")
);
```

For example if I'm given the following values within an object:

```
$myobject->make  = "Volvo";
$myobject->color = "Silver Metallic";
```

I need to use the array above to return

> Silver

Not sure how to plug it all together.

```
echo $cars[0][$myobject->make]...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cars = [
  ['Volvo', 'Silver', 'Silver Metallic'],
  ['BMW', 'Red', 'Sunset Red'],
];

$make = 'Volvo';
$color = 'Silver Metallic';

$result = NULL;
foreach ($cars as $c) {
  if ($c[0] === $make && $c[2] === $color) {
    $result = $c[1];
    break;
  }
}
if ($result !== NULL) {
  echo "found color: ".$result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending how this array is set up, you could do something like this

```
$key = array_search('Silver Metallic', array_column($cars, '2'));
```

In your example, `$key` is `0`, so you can then do something like

```
echo 'Color is ' . $cars[$key][1];
```

Not as scalable as `foreach`, but it could work for a limited subset of data like this

Comment: This wouldn't always work if you had two cars with the color `Silver Metallic`.

Comment: As I said, it's not scalable. Without know what you're trying to do here, it's simply an alternative way on a limited subset of data

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass your search data into the function as an array and leave any one field as an empty string `''`... the function will return the missing field.

```
<?php

$cars = array(
  array("Volvo", "Silver", "Silver Metallic"),
  array("BMW", "Red", "Sunset Red")
);

function getSpecificValue($cars, $data)
{
    foreach ($cars as $car) {

        if ($data['make'] === '') {
            if ($car[1] === $data['color'] && $car[2] === $data['color_name']) {
                return $car[0];
            }
        } elseif ($data['color'] === '') {
            if ($car[0] === $data['make'] && $car[2] === $data['color_name']) {
                return $car[1];
            }
        } elseif ($data['color_name'] === '') {
            if ($car[0] === $data['make'] && $car[1] === $data['color']) {
                return $car[2];
            }
        }
    }
}

$data = [
    'make'       => 'BMW',
    'color'      => 'Red',
    'color_name' => '',
];

$result = getSpecificValue($cars, $data);

var_dump($result);
```